# Where to find PHP function definition

Tags: php

Is there any way I can find PHP's built in functions' definitions?
I'm using an old version of PHP, and I can't use functions like password_hash() because that requires >= 5.5.0. Is it possible for me to find the definition and copy it as a user defined function?

Comment: its better to use latest version of php

Comment: unfortunately it's a company computer that I can't modify

Comment: I think you don't need to modify you only need to upgrade

Answer (score -1):

This might not be the best approach, but by far the easiest way to do so is to have a modren IDE, e.g PHP Storm, Net Beans. They can take you to definitions of builtin or user defined functions there are certain short keys defined with in each IDE.